Simple part in Butterfly lemma proof
Let $u \triangleleft U$ and $v \triangleleft V$. Then, why $u(U \cap v) \triangleleft u(U \cap V)$? This is necessary to write
$$u(U \cap V) / u(U \cap v) \cong (U \cap V) / (u \cap V)(U \cap v)$$
in butterfly lemma. Simple but it seems that I lack something so trivial.

You must have a typo, as your question asks why $u(U\cap V)$ is normal in itself.

You must mean to ask why $u(U \cap v) \triangleleft u(U \cap V)$, right?

Let $xy\in u(U\cap v)$ with $x\in u$ and $y\in U\cap v$.
If $z\in U\cap V$, then $zxz^{-1}\in u$ because $x\in u$, $u\triangleleft U$, and $z\in U$. Also, $zyz^{-1}\in U$ because $z,y\in U$. In addition, $zyz^{-1}\in v$ because $y\in v$, $z\in V$, and $v\triangleleft V$; so $zyz^{-1}\in U\cap v$. Thus, $z(xy)z^{-1} = (zxz^{-1})(zyz^{-1})\in u(U\cap v)$. Thus, $U\cap V\subseteq N_{G}(u(U\cap v))$.
And since $u\subseteq u(U\cap v)$, then $u\subseteq N_G(u(U\cap V))$. Thus, $u(U\cap V) = \langle u,(U\cap V)\rangle\subseteq N_G(u(U\cap v))$, hence $u(U\cap v)\triangleleft u(U\cap V)$.
The equality of $u(U\cap V)$ with $\langle u,(U\cap V)\rangle$ follows because $u\triangleleft U$, so if $x\in u$ and $y\in U\cap V$, then $xy= y(y^{-1}xy)\in (U\cap V)u$, so $u(U\cap V)=(U\cap V)u$, hence $\langle u,U\cap V\rangle = u(U\cap V)$.

@DuckGia every subgroup normalizes itself, so every element of $u(U\cap v)$ normalizes $u(U\cap v)$. In particular, $u$ does. No, it is in general false that $u(U\cap v)\triangleleft u$ because there is absolutely no reason to think that $u(U\cap v)$ is even contained in $u$. That would require $U\cap v\subseteq u$.
